# array_search and destroy logic error

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I am trying to search an array and see if a value is contained in it. If the value is in the array then the index of the value in the array will be passed onto be removed from the array.

The problem is array_search returns FALSE if the value is not found, but since false is a boolean it is also treated as 0. When this is passed to the unset to remove the value from the array the value at index 0 will be removed if array_search returned false.

I am fairly sure it will need to be put into an if statement but how will I handle the response if both an integer and a boolean can both be returned?

Current Code:

```
$pos = array_search($value, $array);
unset($array[$pos]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [`PHP Doc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#refsect1-function.array-search-returnvalues) says..

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
> non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
> Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
> return value of this function.

So you need to do like this

```
<?php
$arr = [1,2,3];
$pos = array_search(4, $arr);
if($pos!==false)
{
unset($arr[$pos]);
}
print_r($arr);
```

**`OUTPUT`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

As you can see the first index is retained.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if($pos !== false)
{
// do your work to unset
}
```

note !== in above code

$x !== $y is True if $x is not equal to $y, or they are not of the same type

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script, hope this will help you...

```
if(in_array($value, $array)){
    $pos = array_search($value, $array);
    unset($array[$pos]); 
}
```